# Google Map, different display between Google Map App and Self-Developing App using Google Map API

Tags: google-maps

I'm developing an android application using Google Map API. My application's targeting audiences are people in Rangoon, Myanmar.

When I open the map using Google Map application on an iPad, the map displayed are more detailed with location name (both in English and Myanmar Language), there are so much locations, roads and signs. But when I open the map using my own application, although I've set location to Myanmar, the map is less detailed. Some roads are missing, the map doesn't show road name. Some location are not displayed.

I wondered that there are some application from Myanmar, they also have map with fully-detailed info, also are Android apps.

I don't know why? May be I need to sign a contract with Google?

Comment: Are you using Places API? https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the latest version of the [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) for displaying all the properties of the maps whether its language or road.

If you want to display additional details on the maps use the Places API provided by Google that would give you more description about a place you are looking for in the map. You can take a look at this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-api-example/).

Views like Satellite or roadmap can be obtained by adding some lines of code in your map view.

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
```

Hope that helps!!